# How to Align CSS form

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't seem to get this form align in the absolute center of the page with top and bottom margins of 25px. I've changed and added things like margin-left:10%; but it just changes the spacing of the pictures instead of moving the whole document as one.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eeEFh/3/embedded/result/

Here's where I changed the css:

```
.box{
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/250/200');
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #666,
              0px 5px 15px 0px #000;
}
```

Comment: You are floating them to the left. Have you consider changing the div into inline-block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to center `.container` , not `.box`

try this:

```
.container {
font-family: Arial;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
width: 780px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I saw this error on your css. You should fix these too,

`.cover .btn {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099CC;border-radius: 0.25em 0.25em 0.25em 0.25em;float: left;margin: 0.5em;padding: 0.5em 1em;}`

`.box .cover .intro {float: left;font-size: 10pt;height: 4.8em;line-height: 1.2em;overflow: hidden;position: relative;width: 160px;
}`